# appx manually installation on windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Kindly suggest what steps should be taken to build an appx file for windows phone 8.1 device. Actually I have build a sample app and want install manually it to windows phone 8.1 device, I have also sign this app and also generate aetx file but unable to install it to device. when I install my app it show a message 'can't install company app'.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy appx file using windowsphone application deployment tool. You need wp8.1 sdk aswell

Deploying Appx guide is here - [How to install Appx (*.appxbundle) on Windows Phone?](http://windowsphonehub.in/tutorials/guide-install-appx-appxbundle-windows-phone/)

Edit:As of 15/1/2020 windowsphonehub.com is no longer online, and in may 15 2015 the article mentioned was deleted. To see the tutorial you must now visit the Web Archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20150421033755/http://windowsphonehub.in/tutorials/guide-install-appx-appxbundle-windows-phone/